# Error when Upgrading Existing ASP.NET Core 1.0 to ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

#### Steps to reproduce

Following this official [.NET Core 1.1 article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/) we upgraded our existing ASP.NET Core 1.0 project to ASP.NET Core 1.1 as follows.

1. In project.json:
   Updated the netcoreapp1.0 target framework to netcoreapp1.1.
   Updated the Microsoft.NETCore.App package version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0.
2. Following this Official EF Blog, we ran the following commands to upgrade to EF Core 1.1:
   Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
   Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre

#### The issue

When compiling the application we got the following error:

```
Assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational' with identity 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' with identity 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets
```

#### Further technical details

Windows 10, VS2015-Update 3 (with latest patches)
ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project using SQL Server 2012.

**NOTE**:
By mistake, when upgrading EF to 1.1, we had run the `Update-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` command that (as it should) did not run and gave us a warning since we are not using any third party database provider. But the above error should not have anything to this mistakenly run command since it did not run anyway - unless it did something internally and then aborted before giving us a warning

Comment: Please post the full project.json file, you probably still have some package that depends on EF Core 1.0.1

Comment: @AndriySvyryd After reading your request for project.json file I found some warnings there. I fixed those warnings. Now the project compiles fine but I get another error that I've posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40686123/1232087). My project.json file is also posted there.