# HTTP 502.5 error after updating ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

#### Steps to reproduce

I used this [official ASP.NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/) articles to upgrade my ASP.NET Core 1.0 app to 1.1. The app compiles fine but when I run the app using F5, I get the following error

**Error**:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:

The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
```

#### Further technical details

Operating system: Windows 10

Visual Studio version: 2015-Update 3 (with latest updates)

**NOTE**:

My app is on development machine(windows 10) running on default built-in IIS express. No server or migration to a different sever is involved.

**Windows Event Log**:

```
Failed to start process with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "C:\DotNet2015\src\ABCTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ABCTest.dll" -wd "C:\DotNet2015\src\ABCTest" -wbe Global\Build30603dd4-5933-4547-8aff-af488d42458c -lse Global\Launchf9d250ad-37e9-4e5b-8375-46f63c747deb', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'.
```

**project.json File**:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-ABCTest-6af8ade3-87ff-4468-a9ce-8bb69c696ab8",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final"  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238"  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5)

Comment: @AlexanderTaran My app is on development machine(windows 10)  running on default built-in IIS express. No server or migration to a different sever is involved.

Comment: I had a similar issue. My app was self-contained and after upgrade to 1.1 and publishing it wasn't anymore, got the same error. I had to install 1.1 Core Framework on the server as @andriy-svyryd mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the `Current` release from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: After I installed the current release from the link you mentioned above it's working now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the 1.1 runtime? When you update your references, it doesn't auto install it.

Comment: When I opened Visual Studio yesterday, I showed me a notification about the release of 1.1. When I clicked on the notification it downloaded an exe that I ran (it had asked me to close the VS before running that installer). After completion of the install, I went to the above mentioned two articles and followed their instructions on how to upgrade the existing 1.0 projects to 1.1. Is there anything else I need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem but my target frame work is **netcoreapp2.0** and I solved it by using Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies per Microsoft document following.

[See here solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAA1FVA0fog&list=PL2kpAKrPYH0RI08vKkj_GWs8CXbUyQYxO)